# JOOQ: DSL.column() with PostgreSQL daterange type

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, date-range

How can I create a column of PostgreSQL's type `daterange` with JOOQ?
I have the Postgres-Extension installed, but I can't figure out how I shall use the [DateRange](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/main/jOOQ-postgres-extensions/src/main/java/org/jooq/postgres/extensions/types/DateRange.java) type when creating a column.

```java
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
dslContext.createTable("foo")
    .column("date_column", DataType<?> ???)
```

The result I want to achieve is:

```sql
create table foo (
    date_column daterange
)
```

I've used `new BuiltInDataType<>(DateRange.class, "daterange")`. It actually creates the `daterange` column, but seems kinda hacky because it's marked as `@internal`.

So, how does one use these types from the PostgreSQL extension?

Comment: I don’t think it exists. Not knowing PostgreSQL’s range types, would it work to represent the range as two `LocalDate` objects in Java? You would need some conversion on saving and retrieving, obviously, and I can’t tell you how to do them. If all else fails use a `String` in Java and format/parse it in getters and setters. I know it’s not a satisfactory solution.

Comment: The `DateRange` type support is meant for generated code and runtime usage only, not for DDL. You could create a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Comment: @OleV.V.: I was referring to jOOQ's support of the PostgreSQL type.